# testNumeric vs is.numeric in R difference checkmate

Tags: r

I am trying to to write a function that returns "nm" if the a variable is numeric, "ch" if it is a character, and "lg" if it is logical and "x" in all other cases (for a class assignment where style and efficiency of code are graded).

it seems to me that version 1 using checkmate:

```
ex03VectorType <- function(x) {
  if (testLogical(x)){
    return("lg")
  } else if (testNumeric(x)){
    return("nm")
  } else if (testCharacter(x)){
    return("ch")
  } else {
    return("x")
  }
}
```

and version 2 without checkmate

```
ex03VectorType <- function(x) {
  if (is.logical(x)){
    return("lg")
  } else if (is.numeric(x)){
    return("nm")
  } else if (is.character(x)){
    return("ch")
  } else {
    return("x")
  }
}
```

both do the same thing. Are they identical or is there a difference? Is one of these better?

Comment: If you look at help `?testLogical`, you'll see that `testLogical` has much more arguments than `is.logical`, so if you need them it will make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Style

You don’t need to use `return()` in your function. A function in R automatically
returns the last line that is being evaluated.

```r
ex03VectorType <- function(x) {
  if (is.logical(x)) {
    "lg"
  } else if (is.numeric(x)) {
    "nm"
  } else if (is.character(x)) {
    "ch"
  } else {
    "x"
  }
}
```

Instead of using `if()`/`else()` we could use `switch()` and `mode()`/`class()`
for more concise code.

```r
# When using `class()` we need to introduce a case for `integer`,
# I'd consider this duplication a "style" disadvantage.
ex03VectorType_switch_class <- function(x) {
  switch(
    class(x),
    logical = "lg",
    numeric = "nm",
    integer = "nm",
    character = "ch",
    "x"
  )
}

# Using `mode()` we get the most concise code. This would be my "style" winner.
ex03VectorType_switch_mode <- function(x) {
  switch(
    mode(x),
    logical = "lg",
    numeric = "nm",
    character = "ch",
    "x"
  )
}
```

## Performance/Efficiency

We can benchmark the functions against each other. The `rbenchmark` package
provides tools for that:

```r
library(rbenchmark)
library(checkmate)

ex03VectorType_checkmate <- function(x) {
  if (testLogical(x)) {
    "lg"
  } else if (testNumeric(x)) {
    "nm"
  } else if (testCharacter(x)) {
    "ch"
  } else {
    "x"
  }
}

benchmark(
  base = {
    ex03VectorType(1)
    ex03VectorType(TRUE)
    ex03VectorType(letters)
  },
  checkmate = {
    ex03VectorType_checkmate(1)
    ex03VectorType_checkmate(TRUE)
    ex03VectorType_checkmate(letters)
  },
  switch_class= {
    ex03VectorType_switch_class(1)
    ex03VectorType_switch_class(TRUE)
    ex03VectorType_switch_class(letters)
  },
  switch_mode = {
    ex03VectorType_switch_mode(1)
    ex03VectorType_switch_mode(TRUE)
    ex03VectorType_switch_mode(letters)
  },
  replications = 10000
)
#>           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
#> 1         base        10000   0.017    1.133     0.015    0.002          0
#> 2    checkmate        10000   0.123    8.200     0.120    0.002          0
#> 3 switch_class        10000   0.015    1.000     0.015    0.001          0
#> 4  switch_mode        10000   0.024    1.600     0.023    0.001          0
#>   sys.child
#> 1         0
#> 2         0
#> 3         0
#> 4         0
```

On my machine `base` and `switch_class` seem to be the fastest variants
(sometimes one of them will be faster, but there doesn’t seem to be a consistent winner).
`checkmate` appears to be
the slowest. There seems to be some inconsistency with `checkmate` when I ran
the first benchmarks it was as fast as the `base` version, but it was never
faster.

## Conclusion

Combining style and efficiency I’d declare the combination of `switch()` and
`class()` the winner. It’s as fast as the `base` variant and
only has one minor style disadvantage, while still being more concise than
the `if()`/`else()` variants.

Comment: I like the use of switch but it needs the caveat this doesn't do exactly the same thing as the if else variant. If you have an object with more than one class, like a numeric matrix, the if statement will return the class it is looking for but the switch statement will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

For a little style flair, I would just parse the first two consonants of the class and then do a check if they are in the list you want.

```r
ex03VectorType_Match <- function(x){
  code <- sub("([^aeiou]{1})[aeiou]?([^aeiou]{1}).*", "\\1\\2", class(x))
  ifelse(
    code %in% c("lg", "nm", "ch"),
    code,
    "x"
  )
}

log_vec <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
chr_vec <- c("a", "b")
num_vec <- c(1, 2)
lst_vec <- c(list(23, 23), list(12, "a"))

ex03VectorType_Match(log_vec)
#> [1] "lg"
ex03VectorType_Match(chr_vec)
#> [1] "ch"
ex03VectorType_Match(num_vec)
#> [1] "nm"
ex03VectorType_Match(lst_vec)
#> [1] "x"
```

Or a one-liner. Here you can just index into the matched class. By setting the last element to check as the known match, we can get the "x":

```r
ex03VectorType_index <- function(x){
  c("nm", "ch", "lg", "x")[
    c("numeric", "character", "logical", class(x)) %in% class(x)
    ][1] 
}

ex03VectorType_index(log_vec)
#> [1] "lg"
ex03VectorType_index(chr_vec)
#> [1] "ch"
ex03VectorType_index(num_vec)
#> [1] "nm"
ex03VectorType_index(lst_vec)
#> [1] "x"
```